# Javascript date in specific format from string

Tags: javascript, datetime, javascript-objects

How can I obtain a javascript Date in ddmmyyyy format without changing Date object to String object?

- I have a `String stringDate = 31/08/2015` (in dd/mm/yyyy format)
- I want to obtain a javascript Date object in same format i.e `dateObj = 31/08/2015` (where dateObj is a javascript Date Object in dd/mm/yyyy format)

Comment: Show some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What does it mean for a `Date` object to be in dd/mm/yyyy format? `Date` objects don't have a format like that. Internally, they're just a count of milliseconds since the UTC epoch.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert a string on the form "dd/mm/yyyy" to a date object in javascript:

```
var stringDate = "31/08/2015";

//split the string into array of date components

stringDate = stringDate.split("/");

//stringDate is now ["31", "08", "2015"]

//convert each array string value to a number, using unary plus
//and feed these values into a new date object

var dateObj = new Date(+stringDate[2], +stringDate[1] - 1, +stringDate[0]);

//note that javascript month values are 0 for Jan ... 11 for Dec, need to subtract one from the month value
```

And how to get a string on the form "dd/mm/yyyy" from a date object:

```
//a date object representing 31 Aug 2015
var dateObject = new Date(2015, 7, 31);

//get the date, month and year values from the date object
var dmy = [
    dateObject.getDate(),
    dateObject.getMonth() + 1,
    dateObject.getFullYear()    
];

//convert to strings and pad with leading zero, if necessary
dmy[0] = ('0' + dmy[0]).slice(-2);
dmy[1] = ('0' + dmy[1]).slice(-2);
dmy[2] = ('0000' + dmy[2]).slice(-4);

//join values with `/` as delimiter
dmy = dmy.join('/');

//dmy is now the string "31/08/2015"
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, tried your code.. but it provides me with date object that is not in dd/mm/yyyy format. Also one date is decremented in the obtained timestamp.

Comment: Hi James. Javascript date objects do not have a specific output format sych as dd/mm/yyyy (they store dates as integers representing number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC, and provide methods to ease date arithmetic). If you want to store dates as date objects, but represent them as strings on dd/mm/yyyy format, the above code will help you to convert your strings to date objects, but you will need another function to get a string on the form dd/mm/yyyy from a date object, as javascript does not have any native methods for this.

Comment: In the answer above, added the steps needed to get a "dd/mm/yyyy" string representation from a date object. Also, please provide some info on the date that was decremented.

Comment: Sorry... But here, the output is same as input, my aim is to have a date object representation of input string

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code examples of what you are attempting, when I test my code, it seems to work exactly as intended.

Comment: Tomas, your code works exactly fine,
However, the output of your code is actually a string, but I want output as a javascript Date object (and not a string) (In the above code, output and input are exactly same.. aren't they..?)

Comment: Tomas, your code works exactly fine,
However, the output of your code is actually a string, but I want output as a javascript Date object (and not a string) (In the above code, output and input are exactly same.. aren't they..?)

Comment: Input and output should not be exactly the same. I provided a new answer, which I hope answers your question better.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your comments on my previous answer it appears as if you are asking for the following:

1. How to create javascript Date objects from strings on the form "dd/mm/yyyy", and
2. How to make these Date objects to be represented as strings on the form "dd/mm/yyyy" when you inspect/use them in other code

The first task is already explained in my previous answer, let us summarize by making a function to do the conversion:

```
//create date object from string on the form "dd/mm/yyyy"

function getDateObjectFromString(dmyString){
    return new Date(
        + dmyString.slice(6,10),
        (+ dmyString.slice(3,5)) - 1,
        + dmyString.slice(0,2)
    );
}
```

Test this with:

```
var dateString = "31/08/2015";
var dateObject = getDateObjectFromString(dateString);
```

If you inspect `dateObject` in the console or use it in code, it will appear as a string (in a different format than what you asked for), but this is because javascript automatically converts Date objects to string representations (or number representations), depending on context, by calling the native `toString()` or `toValue()` methods of the Date object.

You can easily check that `dateString` and `dateObject` are different, and that `dateObject` indeed has the properties of a Date object:

```
console.log(typeof dateString); //returns "string"
console.log(typeof dateObject); //returns "object"

console.log(dateObject.toString()); //returns a browser-dependent and timezone-dependent string
console.log(dateObject.valueOf()); //returns the numeric date representation
```

The second task can be achieved by making your Date objects use a custom `.toString()` method:

```
//custom method to get "dd/mm/yyyy" when called on a Date object
function customDateToString(){
    return [
        ('0' + this.getDate()).slice(-2),
        ('0' + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        ('0000' + this.getFullYear()).slice(-4)
    ].join("/");
}
```

We will avoid messing with `Date.prototype`, but can assign this custom `.toString()` when we create the date objects, revising the `getDateObjectFromString` function:

```
function getDateObjectFromString(dmyString){
    var dateObject = new Date(
        + dmyString.slice(6,10),
        (+ dmyString.slice(3,5)) - 1,
        + dmyString.slice(0,2)
    );
    dateObject.toString = customDateToString;
    return dateObject;
}
```

Now test:

```
var dateString = "31/08/2015";
var dateObject = getDateObjectFromString(dateString);
console.log(dateObject); //displays "31/08/2015"

console.log(dateObject.getDay()); // displays 1 (for Monday), showing that dateObject indeed has the properties/methods of a Date object
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple approach to obtain the desired output.

Means from "**Mon Sep 07 2020 15:21:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**"  TO  "**07/09/2020**".

Suppose you obtain a date object by

`const d = new date();`  // **Mon Sep 07 2020 15:21:31 GMT+0530**

You can convert it to **DD-MM-YYYY** format by attaching the function

`toLocaleDateString('en-GB')`  // **07/09/2020**

So **full code** would be

```js
const d = new Date();
console.log('Original date', d)
const newDate = d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
console.log('Modified date', newDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date("31/0/2015");
```